# Listview in c# not working

Tags: c#, listview

I write this code :

```
public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=person;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from personal", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["name"].ToString());
            listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["lastname"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
}
```

It compiles without any error/warning, but it does not show anything.

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? Do you have any rows retrieved by your query? I recommended to use the debugger before asking

Comment: i debugging and retrived data in subitem. but not show in form.

Comment: Did you define the ListView subitems columns?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: You need to create Columns where the SubItems then can be shown. Columns is a ListView property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding subitems in a ListView you need to define the columns needed.
In your case you need two columns, one for main text (the Name column) and one for the first and only subitem (the LastName field) extracted from your query. Of course this should be changed if in future you want to add more data in your subitems list

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("LastName", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
    ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["name"].ToString());
    listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["lastname"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
}
```

Form MSDN on [ListView.Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) property

> If your ListView control does not have any column headers specified
>   and you set the View property to Details, the ListView control will
>   not display any items.